# C# Mysql - The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: mysql, connection-string

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
    _cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM category";
    MySqlDataReader ret;
    _cmd.Connection = _con;
    _con.Open();
    ret = _cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    _con.Close();

    return ret;
```

Yet, I am getting a strange error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

The connection string is being read correctly from web.config (I can see this using the debuger). I also have other methods that use the same connectionString (that are used to insert data) and they work correctly. Anything I am missing here?!

This is the method I am trying to invoke:

```
  public MySqlDataReader ExecuteReader(String sql, MySqlParameter[] param)
    {
        if (param != null)
            _cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

        _cmd.CommandText = sql;
        MySqlDataReader ret;

        _con.Open();
        ret = _cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        return ret;
    }
```

It is invoked from this web service:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string[] GetCategories()
        {
            String sql = "SELECT CategoryName FROM category";
            DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper();
            MySqlDataReader dr = dh.ExecuteReader(sql, null);
            List<String> categories = new List<string>();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                categories.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();

            return categories.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: the error message doesn't lie, can you post the whole code the one with the dictionary on it?

Comment: are you sure this is the portion that gave this error?

Comment: I posted the whole code.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? I suppose when you try to read from the MySqlDataReader in the caller of the above code.

Comment: It happens on the following line:
ret = _cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);